# Change sorting by custom field public directory (Jomla)

Tags: joomla, directory, sort-order

I have a public directory profile listing members and custom fields. The default order in the public view is by the Contact Name. I would like to change the order to one of custom field "Start Date". Is this possible with Joomla 3.9.5 and CiviCRM 5.13.2?
If not, can I append the sorting to the URL?